# Editing a Wordpress plugin to add my own functionality

Tags: php, wordpress, csv

I'm trying to add more fields to this php script. By default what it does is allow visitors to your site to input their name and email address to register it into a list on the back end, which I can then export as a .csv file. At the moment I'm attempting to add fields for phone number, city, state, ect. I've been able to add the fields, but they don't register on the back end. Actually when I finish adding a field, it breaks every other field. Here is my php code. Anything referencing number, or sml_number is what I'm trying to add.

sml.php:

```
            // Plugin Activation
            function sml_install() {
                global $wpdb;
                $table = $wpdb->prefix."sml";
                $structure = "CREATE TABLE $table (
                    id INT(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                    sml_name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
                    sml_email VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
                    sml_number VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
                UNIQUE KEY id (id)
                );";
                $wpdb->query($structure);

            }
            register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'sml_install' );

            // Plugin Deactivation
            function sml_uninstall() {
                global $wpdb;

            }
            register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'sml_uninstall' );

            // Left Menu Button
            function register_sml_menu() {
                add_menu_page('Subscribers', 'Subscribers', 'add_users', dirname(__FILE__).'/index.php', '',   plugins_url('sml-admin-icon.png', __FILE__), 58.122);
            }
            add_action('admin_menu', 'register_sml_menu');

            // Generate Subscribe Form 

            function smlsubform($atts=array()){
                extract(shortcode_atts(array(
                    "prepend" => '',  
                    "showname" => true,
                    "nametxt" => 'Name:',
                    "nameholder" => 'Enter your name.',
                    "emailtxt" => 'Email:',
                    "emailholder" => 'Enter your email address.',
                    "numbertxt" => 'Phone Number:',
                    "numberholder" => 'Enter your Phone Number.',
                    "showsubmit" => true,
                    "submittxt" => 'Subscribe',
                    "jsthanks" => false,
                    "thankyou" => 'Thank you for subscribing to our mailing list!'
                ), $atts));

                $return = '<form class="sml_subscribe" method="post"><input class="sml_hiddenfield" name="sml_subscribe" type="hidden" value="1">';

                if ($prepend) $return .= '<p class="prepend">'.$prepend.'</p>';

                if ($_POST['sml_subscribe'] && $thankyou) { 
                    if ($jsthanks) {
                        $return .= "<script>window.onload = function() { alert('".$thankyou."'); }</script>";
                    } else {
                        $return .= '<p class="sml_thankyou">'.$thankyou.'</p>'; 
                    }
                }


                if ($showname) $return .= '<p class="sml_name"><label class="sml_namelabel" for="sml_name">'.$nametxt.'</label><input class="sml_nameinput" placeholder="'.$nameholder.'" name="sml_name" type="text" value=""></p>';
                $return .= '<p class="sml_email"><label class="sml_emaillabel" for="sml_email">'.$emailtxt.'</label><input class="sml_emailinput" name="sml_email" placeholder="'.$emailholder.'" type="text" value=""></p>';
                $return .= '<p class="sml_number"><label class="sml_numberlabel" for="sml_number">'.$numbertxt.'</label><input class="sml_numberinput" name="sml_number" placeholder="'.$numberholder.'" type="text" value=""></p>';
                if ($showsubmit) $return .= '<p class="sml_submit"><input name="submit" class="btn sml_submitbtn" type="submit" value="'.($submittxt?$submittxt:'Submit').'"></p>';
                $return .= '</form>';

                return $return;
            }
            add_shortcode( 'smlsubform', 'smlsubform' );

            // Handle form Post
            if ($_POST['sml_subscribe']) {
                $name = $_POST['sml_name'];
                $email = $_POST['sml_email'];
                $number = $_POST['sml_number'];
                if (is_email($email)) {

                    $exists = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."sml where sml_email like '".$wpdb->escape($email)."' limit 1");
                    if (mysql_num_rows($exists) <1) {
                        $wpdb->query("insert into ".$wpdb->prefix."sml (sml_name, sml_email, sml_number) values ('".$wpdb->escape($name)."', '".$wpdb->escape($email)."', '".$wpdb->escape($number)."')");
                    }
                }
            }

            function plugin_get_version() {
                $plugin_data = get_plugin_data( __FILE__ );
                $plugin_version = $plugin_data['Version'];
                return $plugin_version;
            }

            ?>
```

index.php

```
<div class="wrap">

    <?php screen_icon( 'themes' ); ?>
    <h2>Mail list subscribers</h2>

    <div id="poststuff">

        <div id="post-body" class="metabox-holder columns-3">

            <!-- main content -->
            <div id="post-body-content">

            <form method="post" action="?page=<?php echo esc_js(esc_html($_GET['page'])); ?>">
            <input name="sml_remove" value="1" type="hidden" />
                        <?php 
                        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST" and $_POST['sml_remove']) {
                            if ($_GET['rem']) $_POST['rem'][] = $_GET['rem'];
                            $count = 0;
                            if (is_array($_POST['rem'])) {
                                foreach ($_POST['rem'] as $id) { 
                                    $wpdb->query("delete from ".$wpdb->prefix."sml where id = '".$wpdb->escape($id)."' limit 1"); 
                                    $count++; 
                                }
                                $message = $count." subscribers have been removed successfully.";
                            }
                        }

                        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST" and $_POST['sml_import']) {
                            $correct = 0;
                            if($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) {
                                if(!$_FILES['file']['error'])  {
                                    $file = file_get_contents ($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
                                    $lines = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $file);
                                    if (count($lines)) {
                                        $sql = array();
                                        foreach ($lines as $data) {
                                            $data = explode(',', $data);
                                            $num = count($data);
                                            $row++;

                                            if (is_email(trim($data[0]))) {
                                                $c = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."sml where sml_email LIKE '".$wpdb->escape(trim($data[0]))."' limit 1", ARRAY_A);
                                                if (!is_array($c)) {                                            
                                                    $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO ".$wpdb->prefix."sml (sml_email, sml_name, sml_number) VALUES ('".$wpdb->escape(trim($data[0]))."', '".$wpdb->escape(trim($data[1]))."', '".$wpdb->escape(trim($data[0]))."')");
                                                    $correct++;
                                                } else { $exists++; }
                                            } else { $invalid++; }
                                        }

                                    } else { $message = 'Oh no! Your CSV file does not apear to be valid, please check the format and upload again.'; }

                                    if (!$message) {
                                        $message = $correct.' records have been imported. '.($invalid?$invalid.' could not be imported due to invalid email addresses. ':'').($exists?$exists.' already exists. ':'');
                                    }

                                } else {
                                    $message = 'Ooops! There seems to of been a problem uploading your csv';
                                }
                            }                               
                        }
                        //echo $sql;
                        if ($message) { echo '<div style="padding: 5px;" class="updated"><p>'.$message.'</p></div>'; }

                        ?>

                        <table cellspacing="0" class="wp-list-table widefat fixed subscribers">
                          <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th style="" class="manage-column column-cb check-column" id="cb" scope="col"><input type="checkbox"></th>
                                <th style="" class="manage-column column-name" id="name" scope="col">Name<span class="sorting-indicator"></span></th>
                                <th style="" class="manage-column column-email" id="email" scope="col"><span>Email Address</span><span class="sorting-indicator"></span></th>
                                <th style="" class="manage-column column-number" id="number" scope="col"><span>Number</span><span class="sorting-indicator"></span></th>

                           </thead>

                            <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <th style="" class="manage-column column-cb check-column" scope="col"><input type="checkbox"></th>
                                <th style="" class="manage-column column-name" scope="col"><span>Name</span><span class="sorting-indicator"></span></th>
                                <th style="" class="manage-column column-email" scope="col"><span>Email Address</span><span class="sorting-indicator"></span></th>
                                <th style="" class="manage-column column-number" scope="col"><span>Number</span><span class="sorting-indicator"></span></th>
                            </tfoot>

                            <tbody id="the-list">

                            <?php 

                                $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."sml");
                                if (count($results)<1) echo '<tr class="no-items"><td colspan="3" class="colspanchange">No mailing list subscribers have been added.</td></tr>';
                                else {
                                    foreach($results as $row) {

                                        echo '<tr>
                                                    <th class="check-column" style="padding:5px 0 2px 0"><input type="checkbox" name="rem[]" value="'.esc_js(esc_html($row->id)).'"></th>
                                                    <td>'.esc_js(esc_html($row->sml_name)).'</td>
                                                    <td>'.esc_js(esc_html($row->sml_email)).'</td>
                                                    <td>'.esc_js(esc_html($row->sml_number)).'</td>

                                              </tr>';




                                    }
                                }

                            ?>


                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <br class="clear">
                        <input class="button" name="submit" type="submit" value="Remove Subscribers" /> <a class="button" href="<?php echo plugins_url( 'export-csv.php', __FILE__ ); ?>">Export List</a>
                </form>
                <br class="clear">


                <div class="meta-box-sortables">



            <div id="postbox-container-1" class="postbox-container">
                    <div class="meta-box-sortables">

                    </div> 
                </div> 
            </div>
            <br class="clear">
    </div>

</div>
```

export-csv.php

```
<?php 
require_once '../../../wp-load.php';
if (current_user_can('manage_options')) {
    header("Content-type: application/force-download"); 
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="subscribers'.date('YmdHis').'.csv"');  
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."sml");
    echo "First Name,Last Name,Email Address\r\n";
    if (count($results))  {
        foreach($results as $row) {
            $n = doSplitName($row->sml_name);
            echo $n['first'].','.$n['last'].','.$row->sml_email."\r\n";
        }
    }
}

function doSplitName($name) {
    $results = array();

    $r = explode(' ', $name);
    $size = count($r);

    if (mb_strpos($r[0], '.') === false) {
        $results['salutation'] = '';
        $results['first'] = $r[0];
    } else {
        $results['salutation'] = $r[0];
        $results['first'] = $r[1];
    }

    if (mb_strpos($r[$size - 1], '.') === false) {
        $results['suffix'] = '';
    } else {
        $results['suffix'] = $r[$size - 1];
    }

    $start = ($results['salutation']) ? 2 : 1;
    $end = ($results['suffix']) ? $size - 2 : $size - 1;

    $last = '';
    for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++) {
        $last .= ' '.$r[$i];
    }
    $results['last'] = trim($last);

    return $results;
}
?>
```

Any and all help is much appreciated. Or even just a push in the right direction. I've been working on this for weeks, and I'm not terrific at php. Thank you very much.

Comment: For a start, you need to include them in the INSERT statement in your index.php code. Have you amended the database table so your new fields are in there, too?

Comment: Are you starting with a plugin from the WordPress repo? If so, which one?  When you write, 'breaks every other field,' what do you mean exactly? Can you use a MySQL client program (e.g. phpmyadmin) to look at the table your plugin is supposed to create, to make sure it's present and correct?  You might try http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ for help with this if you haven't done so already.

Comment: It is in the insert statement. Isn't this how it should look?
$wpdb->query("INSERT INTO ".$wpdb->prefix."sml (sml_email, sml_name, sml_number) VALUES ('".$wpdb->escape(trim($data[0]))."', '".$wpdb->escape(trim($data[1]))."', '".$wpdb->escape(trim($data[0]))."')");

Also the plugin is http://wordpress.org/plugins/mail-subscribe-list/

And by breaking every field, I mean name and email work before I insert number, but after I amend it to the list they don't work.

Comment: Hey, just as a tip: if you want more exposure, try to post only the relevant part of the code in your question. It's better to be safe than sorry, but finding the right balance will reduce the "wall of text" effect.

Comment: Sorry for the wall of text also. Problem is I don't know exactly what's making it not work. I'm not getting an error, it just stops working. In the future I won't post a wall of text. Sorry.